# Decomposition of universal enveloping algebra of a semisimple Lie algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $\frak{g}$ be a semisimple Lie algebra and $U(\frak{g})$ its universal enveloping algebra. We have a decomposition $\frak{g}=\frak{n}^-\oplus\frak{b}$ where $\frak{b}=\frak{h}\oplus\frak{n}^+$. By PBW we have an isomorphism of vector spaces $$U({\frak{g}})\simeq U({\frak{n}^-})\otimes_k U({\frak{b}}) $$

Now if we extend scalars on the right then we can regard $U({\frak{n}^-})\otimes_k U({\frak{b}})$ as a left $U(\frak{n}^-)$-module. Then the above isomorphism is actually an isomorphism of left $U(\frak{n}^-)$-modules right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I think the right hand side is obviously a left $U(\mathfrak n^-)$-module, so I don't know what you mena by extending scalars there; if anything, one might want to give an argument why the *left* hand side $U(\mathfrak g)$ is a left $U(\mathfrak n^-)$-module. But that is true as well. Cf. related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3920005/96384 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3975638/96384.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inclusion map $ι$ from $^-$ to $$ induces a homomorphism of algebras $\operatorname{U}(ι)$ from $\operatorname{U}(^-)$ to $\operatorname{U}()$, which allows us to regard $\operatorname{U}(^-)$ as a subalgebra of $\operatorname{U}()$.
We can similarly regard $\operatorname{U}()$ as a subalgebra of $\operatorname{U}()$.

The above isomorphism af vector spaces is then given by
$$
  Φ
  \colon
  \operatorname{U}(^-) ⊗_ \operatorname{U}()
  \to
  \operatorname{U}() \,,
  \quad
  x ⊗ y \mapsto x y  \,.
$$
The $\operatorname{U}(^-)$-module structure on the left-hand side of this isomorphism is given by
$$
  x' ⋅ (x ⊗ y) = (x' x) ⊗ y \,,
$$
and the module structure on the right-hand side is given by the multiplication of $\operatorname{U}()$.
Therefore,
$$
  Φ(x' ⋅ (x ⊗ y))
  =
  Φ((x' x) ⊗ y)
  =
  x' x y
  =
  x' ⋅ xy
  =
  x' ⋅ Φ(x ⊗ y) \,.
$$
This shows that $Φ$ is indeed a homomorphism – and thus isomorphism – of $\operatorname{U}(^-)$-modules.
(It as also a homomorphism of right $\operatorname{U}()$-modules, and therefore an isomorphism of $\operatorname{U}(^-)$-$\operatorname{U}()$-bimodules.)